# If I hang from the ceiling of the elevator which is falling freely then will I experience weightlessness?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, reference-frames, acceleration

We all know that while the lift (or elevator) is accelerating downwards we feel less weight, now suppose I hang from the ceiling with the help of a stick in some cavity of the ceiling itself, then will I feel the same?

Comment: Why do you need to hang from the ceiling?

Comment: Hanging uses the same principle as standing does (just replace the normal force of the floor with the normal force of the bar), so the situations are the same if the elevator is in free fall.

Comment: @Triatticus Thanks for answering.

Comment: It's not really an answer it's just an expansion of Jon's comment, I suppose it technically removes the need for the question though.

Comment: @Triatticus Actually I also had applied the same reasoning, I just wanted to confirm my assertion

Comment: Once you let go, you'll feel weightless for a short time (ignoring any air resistance), until you hit the ground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of feeling less force by the floor pushing up on your feet if standing on the floor, you will feel less force pulling up on your arms by the stick or rope or whatever it is you are hanging on.

Hope this helps